# Login with Facebook with multiple dynamic domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, multi-tenant

I am working on a RoR application with multi tenant, each tenant has one store and have many clients. The users can access the store changing the subdomain, something like this:

```
 store_name.myapplication.com
```

The tenant set his store name. So I have many subdomains in my application.

I want to implement Facebook login in the stores, where the client can be registered with Facebook. In my Facebook app I define the site URL and app domains, but my app domains are constantly created and I can't register all in Facebook.

There's any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878