# Same Facebook login with multiple apps

Tags: facebook

I would like to use the same Facebook login for multiple apps.

I know I can use `urlSchemeSuffix` to distinguish between apps and add the bundle ID's to the FB web admin. However, I need to do this for possibly 2000 apps (white label apps). Adding so many seems a bit impractical and it may not even let me add so many to the list.

Is there any other way of enabling SSO for multiple apps with differing bundle ID's?

Comment: Why such a white label solution is not a good idea IMHO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878