# Use multiple App Domains for one facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I am using Facebook ads API and I want to use multiple App Domains for one Facebook app. Because I am using white label domains and all domains are accessing one server. Is there any way to add multiple App domains. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSAPs.png)

Comment: Why that is not a good idea, I have outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878

Comment: Thanks for the help but the review process has made it more hectic...