# Facebook SSO in multi tenant architecture

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on, multi-tenant, google-sso

For Facebook/Google SSO (single-sgin-on), 
the normal procedure is to create a separate FB developer app and 
get the key pairs & integrate with the application.

If white labeling is allowed as below:

```
client1.com points to client1.ourproduct.com 
client2.com points to client2.ourproduct.com
client3.com points to client3.ourproduct.com
```

Is there any better approach to avoid creating FB developer 
apps for each customer/client and integrate with the application?
I mean, is there any way to manage with a single developer app 
and manage with this esp when white labeling is allowed?
Kindly suggest.

Comment: My thoughts on the issue from a little while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878