# Facebook one App multiple websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I currently work on CMS which should give a user (client) an option to publish some article also to his facebook page.

so all what I need from client is to give me permissions to manage his page(s) and after that he has access to a button to publish also on facebook page that article.

My question is, is there any option to have only one facebook app and use it for all clients and all websites which are using that CMS?

And if there is that option, in privacy policy URL and Terms of service URL could be link to our company sites (with relevant content of course)?

I am sorry if there was asked question like this, but I did not find satisfying answer for this problem.

Thanks for your response

Comment: If you handle login to your app from your CMS domain, it would be possible. But you can not use the same app on an arbitrary number of domains. And PP/ToS are “fixed” links, you can not specify different ones for different customers. The places those get linked to for end users to read, don’t have any such context to begin with.

Comment: Thank You for your response, so If I understood it. I can make login via cms domain and after I can send acquired page token to the client website? Dont you know if this is some kind of "best practises" how to avoid creating new apps again and again for each client?

Comment: You can theoretically use a token “from” anywhere, once you got it. But the possibility to log in to your app will be tied to its set domain to begin with. I wrote a more extensive answer on the general issue of “white labeling” such apps for customers; most of that should still hold true today ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878