# Authenticating with third party services when whitelabeled

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-analytics-api, twitter-oauth, google-my-business-api, white-labelling

I have a platform that allows users to connect services such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google My Business etc and I provide a whitelabel option where customers can use their own domain and their users are unaware that it is my platform they are using.

If a user tries to authenticate these services from a different domain it will fail and also show my business name and logo rather than the company whitelabeling.

Some strategies I am looking at:
1. Require each third party to create their own developer accounts and uses their credentials.
2. Register a third generic domain with developer accounts that will allow white labeled users to connect via this entity without knowing my service is the underlying platform.

I am also not sure if this would break any terms and conditions for services such as facebook.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

cheers
Paul.

Comment: Re: 1. - then they would all have to go through app review on their own as well (at least for Facebook, not sure to what extend other providers have a similar procedure.)

Comment: _“and also show my business name and logo rather than the company whitelabeling”_ - well they would see _your_ app name and logo in the login dialog anyway (again, talking about Facebook, not sure if the others provide any ways to overwrite that.)

Comment: @CBroe .. I have disabled social login for whitelabeled accounts. The connect to these services to manage their data on these services. eg. facebook business page etc. The users should not see that they are authenticating with my service so need the application name and logo to be for the whitelabeling company.

Comment: I don’t know what you are talking about now, in the question title you are talking about authenticating with third party services, and the question starts with something about “connecting” to those services - but now you say, you “disabled social login” for these accounts to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe .. we have disabled social login for whitelabel users for now (they can only login via username\password). But some of the functionality on our platform requires them to connect their online accounts if they want to work with their facebook business pages, or twitter accounts, google analytics etc.  I would imagine a solution to this problem would mean we would turn social login back on again.

Comment: Yes, connecting to these networks in any way, usually requires that users log in to the respective apps and grant them permissions. So for that, you need the social login part. I’ve elaborated on the options for login to a Facebook app from multiple domains a while back, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952548/1427878, most of that still stands. (The mentioned drawbacks are probably less of a concern in your situation, that applies more to a large user base that publishes content through the app.)